React Native - How to render a maximum amount of items per load?
I want to load only a max number of items per load. After looking up FlatList, it seems that thats possible not with FlatList but with VirtualizedList. However, no matter what props I use, nothing is really happening. Im trying to render 5 items per load.
  <VirtualizedList
    data={products}
        getItem={(data, i) => data[i]}
        getItemCount={(data) => data.length}
        renderItem={({item}) => <Item item={item} />}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        initialNumToRender={5}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
        windowSize={5}
        updateCellsBatchingPeriod={5}
  </VirtualizedList>

